# "unkown parser error" in c++ netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

Sorry in advance, I posted a picture but I don't have the rep yet :( The error at line 1 says "Unknown parser error" repeated over four lines, and starting at the ReadFile class line pretty much each line has an error saying "unexpected token". I have included all of the custom header files from a folder either by right clicking "header" under project and adding the folder containing them or by right clicking the project name itself and adding the folder there. The private folder containing the private snippets of the headers are also included. Anyone have any ideas? This is for a free collection of lectures by Stanford, and you have to download and install their custom headers.. The instructor is using Visual c++, but that shouldn't mean I can't use the files for Netbeans right, their just .h files..?

```
#include "genlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "map.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "set.h"
using namespace std;

void ReadFile(ifstream &in, Map<int> &m)
{
    while (true) {
        string word;
        in >> word;
        if (in.fail()) break;
        if (m.containsKey(word)) 
            m[word]++;
        else
            m[word] = 1;
    }
    Map<int>::Iterator itr = m.iterator();
    string max;
    int maxCount = 0;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        string key = itr.next();
        if (m[key] > maxCount) {
            max = key;
            maxCount = m[key];
        }
    }
    cout << "Max is " << max << " = " << maxCount << endl;
}

void TestRandom()
{
    Set<int> seen;
    while (true) {
        int num = RandomInteger(1, 100);
        if (seen.contains(num)) break;
        seen.add(num);
    }
    Set<int>::Iterator itr = seen.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) 
        cout << itr.next() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in("burgh.txt");
    Map<int> counts;
    ReadFile(in, counts);
    Randomize();
    TestRandom();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post the error

Comment: Please post the error by editing your original question, and delete these comments. Use the formatting tools to make them more readable.

Comment: Do you want me to add the error as a comment? Because each error (which is on the first header file declaration, and every line in the ReadFile class usually has multiple "unexpected token". Like, the ReadFile class line has "unexpected token: =". The only exception is the first header declaration which states "unknown parser error" on top of itself four times.

Answer (score 0):

In your ReadFile function (in multiple places) you are attempting to use a string as the key to a Map with integers as keys.

```
string word;
in >> word;
if (in.fail()) break;
if (m.containsKey(word)) 
    m[word]++;
```

In order to do this properly you will need to parse your string input into an integer. This can be achieved through the [stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) function or similar.

Example

```
string word;
in >> word;
int iKey = stoi(word, nullptr);
if (in.fail()) break;
if (m.containsKey(iKey)) 
    m[iKey]++;
```

Comment: Ok so for m.containskey(word)) should I define an int say "int iKey" and replace 'word' with m.containskey(ikey=stoi(word,&sz)); as well as m[iKey]++? I haven't used that function before so just want to check it out.

Comment: Ok I just tried it and got this message aftercompiling  cc1plus: fatal error: ../../../Desktop/cs106lib-0.3.1/headers: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o] Error 1                                                                                                                It's talking about my headers  not existing but I've already included my header folder using right click project name and right click header under my project name. It's in the directory as well...

Comment: This would make sense as to why there's an error on almost every line in the ReadFile class but it's only on "genlib.h" however the "unknown parser error" like I said occurs four times on top of itself on line 1.

Comment: do you have a genlib.h or did you mean stdlib.h?

Comment: I have cynig with netbeans, but in the project itself I also have my header folder from the stanford libraries, which includes a "genlib.h" file, which is the one declared in line 1.

Comment: This is a header error obviously, does this folder (../../../Desktop/cs106lib-0.3.1/headers) have all of your headers including the genlib.h file in the base directory, not in a subdirectory?

Comment: Yes genlib is in the header directory, there is a "private" subdirectory inside of "headers" which includes another "set.h" and "map.h" but only the private section of their respective interfaces. Would this not already be included?